# A Group of Partygoers

Tags: word, knowledge, word-property

Feeling adventurous, I decided to have a party, so I invited my friends: Astrid, Connor, Clinton, Lewis, and Michael. What's my name?

There could be a few possibilities, but there's only one right answer.

Hint:

> Connor isn't really skilled at anything, but he's vital to our group.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If we consider the following...

> aSTRid > Strength

> CONnor > Constitution

> clINTon > Intelligence

> leWIS > Wisdom

> miCHAel > Charisma

I would say the answer would be something like

> DEXter > Dexterity

Comment: Makes sense with the title too, as in a DnD party! +1

Comment: Yup! And you can verify it with its [definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dexter)